# ObjectMessage.setObject() throws javax.jms.JMSException for no apparently reason

Tags: java, glassfish, jms

Having a custom object like this:

```
package Messages;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class MessageObject implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private TextMessage message;
private String state; 
private String sender;
private String receiver;

public MessageObject() {

}

public TextMessage getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(TextMessage message) {
    this.message = message;
}
* the rest of the getters and setters *

}
```

Then I create I try to send to my jms queue an ObjectMessage containing my custom message object:

```
try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();

        QueueConnectionFactory factory = 
        (QueueConnectionFactory)context.lookup("tiwconnectionfactory");
        Queue queue = (Queue) context.lookup("tiwqueue");
        Connection connection = factory.createConnection();
        connection.start(); 
        Session session= connection.createSession(false, 
        javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);


        MessageObject mymessage = new MessageObject();


         ObjectMessage object = session.createObjectMessage();


        TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage();
        message.setText("Hi");


        mymessage.setState("still not read");
        mymessage.setMessage(message);
        mymessage.setSender("Peter");
        mymessage.setReceiver("John");


        object.setObject(mymessage);


        producer.send(object);
```

When trying to run the code, exception throwed is:

```
[2018-11-11T19:20:07.270+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1541960407270] [levelValue: 1000] [[ javax.jms.JMSException:MQJMSRA_DM4001::Exception:ObjectMessage.setObject()object=Messages.MessageObject@d8b66e3:message=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectTextPacktatcom.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectObjectPacket.setObject(DirectObjectPacket.java:218)
```

So what the problem is? I dont find any errors in my code, and my object is serializable.

Comment: Is `TextMessage`  also serializable?

Comment: @ThomasKläger I'm not sure about that. Do you think thats the problem? Should the error be "exception not serializable" instead of the one i'm getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used google to pick apart your error message:

```
[2018-11-11T19:20:07.270+0100] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid: _ThreadID=28 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1541960407270] [levelValue: 1000] 
[[ javax.jms.JMSException:MQJMSRA_DM4001::Exception:ObjectMessage.setObject()
  object=Messages.MessageObject@d8b66e3:
  message=com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectTextPacket
  at com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectObjectPacket.setObject(DirectObjectPacket.java:218)
```

It seems that the `TextMessage` object is actually an instance of `com.sun.messaging.jms.ra.DirectTextPacket`.

However, for your `MessageObject` to be serializable all of its fields need to be serializable too. As `DirectTextPacket` is not serializable, your `MessageObject` is not serializable.

---

To answer the question "why do you get this exception instead of `NotSerializableException`"?

This is because JMS wraps exceptions like `NotSerializableException` into its own exceptions.

---

What I do not understand: why do you want your `MessageObject` to contain a wrapped `TextMessage`? Why not add the text itself into your `MessageObject`?

Comment: you'r right, I changed the textmessage to a String, and works perfectly now.